# Hook (or other way) to find out when another plugin is activated / installed

Tags: plugins, hooks, installation

Is there some way to run a function when another plugin is being installed and/or activated?

Basically I need something like `register_activation_hook` only for other plugins.

The use case:

I want to check for CVE patches on my own server when a plugin is installed / activated.

The only thing I can think of right now is manually keeping track of activated and installed plugins, but this is not a very clean solution.

Comment: Why can't you use that function? It gets passed to is a plugin file name you can test against - [Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/)

Comment: Because I don't know what plugins will be activated on the system. Hence I have no way of "binding" plugins by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`activated_plugin`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/activated_plugin) and [`deactivated_plugin`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/deactivated_plugin), see the wordpress documentation:

Comment: Wow. Not sure why I didn't find those. That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Is there also a thing like that for installation of plugins by any chance?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can always get an up to date list of installed plugins via the `get_plugins()` function.  If you're already keeping a running list of activated plugins you can get inactive plugins with something like `$inactive_plugins = array_diff(get_plugins(),$active_plugins)`